# unable to uninstall netbeans ide in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-12.04

I am not able to uninstall NetBeans in ubuntu os and I don't know where I install it. I checked the snap store or apt store but I couldn't find it. I download the NetBeans .deb file from the official site.

I try from the command line or ubuntu store every possible thing I try not able to uninstall

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
which NetBeans
```

You can also search like this:

```
sudo find / -name "netbeans"
```

Also, you can uninstall it from the same `.deb` file like this:

```
sudo dpkg -r netbeans-filename.deb
```